# Alternatives to background-size?

Tags: css

Typically IE doesn't support the CSS3 `background-size` and I'm looking for a workaround.

I tried placing an image as the first thing on a page an setting the CSS such as:

```
#bg_stretch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Works good width wise, but adding a `height: 100%` doesn't work so it covers the length of the page.

Comment: Make sure you've defined a height for `html` and `body`, and whatever else may be containing your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/VMzFB/

**CSS:**

```
#stretch {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -10;

    /* only ie7 needs this */
    height: 100%;
}
#stretch img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="stretch">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/256x256/f0f/fff" />
</div>
```

If that's not quite right, look at the ideas here:

http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `bottom:0;` to that CSS rule.